# Location Service in Android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I am developing an emergency application in Android. I would like to get GPS location or network location by default, even though the Location service is OFF...

I figured out the below code would do whatever I was looking for:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But most of them on Google are saying it is a bug not recommended type of usage if so what is the best way to get location when location is OFF?

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use location services when location services is turned off? You probably can't. Perhaps the best you can do is inform the user if your application discovers that it's not getting up-to-date location information.

Comment: Is this for all the versions... even for versions below 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

> But most of them on Google are saying it is a bug not recommended type of usage

That particular script-kiddie hack has not worked in years.

> what is the best way to get location when location is OFF?

There is no way to get the location when the location service is off, except via crude mechanisms, such as the geo-IP stuff that some Web sites use. Apps are not allowed to access location information when location services are off for privacy reasons. If you determine that location services are off, you are welcome to ask the user to turn them on.

Comment: Is this for all the versions... even for versions below 4.0?

Comment: @TheDevMan: This has been the case since Android 1.5.

Comment: But I thought we can enable the GPS programatically below 4.0? Isn't that true?

Comment: @TheDevMan: Malware authors have script-kiddie unpatched security flaws that they can use on various older Android versions. So, the real question is: are you a malware author? If you are not, then **quit trying to be a malware author**. If the user wants your app to have locations, the user will enable locations.

Comment: Nope. I just want to make the user comfortable in using my application by giving the user an option to get the location automatically even the service is OFF... The only option is to prompt the user to enable it.. Right?